# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID'

Tags: database, magento2.3, data-migration-tool

I am using this data-migration-tool,
When i migrate from magento 1.9.3.2 to magento 2.3,getting below error,

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID'

i tried many times upload fresh DB,still getting this issue

Comment: Do you have orders with no increment_id in your database? That shouldn't be possible since there is an unique index on that column, but the key in your error looks like that

Comment: Do you have orders with no increment_id in your database?
>>>which table i have to check ?

Comment: `sales_flat_order` in your Magento 1 database.

Comment: yes sales_flat_order,entity_id is auto increment and all entity_id are unique

Comment: not `entity_id` but `increment_id`

Comment: yes @HelgeB you are right first few entries have no increment_id(empty there),thank you so much.
but how can i resolved so that when i migrate,this error would not come

Comment: I would insert arbitrary increment_ids for that rows if that's ok for you. Just pay attention to keep the values in that column unique and you will make it :-) Good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89928/discussion-between-sumeet-bajaj-and-helgeb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs if there are orders in the Magento 1 database with no `increment_id` set. You can check if you have such orders by running the following SQL statement in your Magento 1 database:

```
select count(*) from sales_flat_order where increment_id = '' OR increment_id is NULL;
```

If the returned value is greater than 0, you should update the tables `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_grid` in such a way to ensure that all your orders have increment_ids and those are unique.

If you find `incrment_ids` in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table for all orders, just take the values from there with the following statemen:

```
update sales_flat_order o 
join sales_flat_order_grid g 
    on o.entity_id = g.entity_id  
set o.increment_id = g.increment_id 
where o.increment_id = '' OR o.increment_id is NULL;
```

If you don't find orders without any increment_id it might be the best option to create arbitrary increment_ids. For example you can use a SQL update statement which builds an `increment_id` based on the `entity_id` and a prefix of your choice (just replace the  prefix in the sample statements with something which doesn't conflict with existing increment_ids):

```
update sales_flat_order set increment_id = concat ('990000', entity_id) where increment_id is null;
update sales_flat_order_grid set increment_id = concat ('990000', entity_id) where increment_id is null;
```

Comment: thanks @HelgeB, you are awesome,fantastic,thanks for your valuable time